# proving bitstrings

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

1.Let it be $a_n$ the number of bitstrings which contain 000 How would I prove that for $n\ge4$:
$$a_n = a_{(n-1)} + a_{(n-2)} + a_{(n-3)} + 2^{n-3}$$

Comment: 2 should be a separate question and needs rewriting for clarity

Comment: The formula is already incorrect for $n = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

To make an $n$ bit string containing $000$, you can start with any $n-3$ bit string and append $000$ or start with an $n-1$ bit string containing $000$ and append a $1$ or start with an $n-2$ bit string containing $000$ and append $11$ or start with an $n-3$ bit string containing $000$ and append $111$